# Libvirt: how to pass qemu command line args?

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I have the current libvirt 1.2.20
i want to pass to my machine create with virt-manager
some qemu flags.
I edited the file and add

```
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
          <qemu:arg value='-L pc-bios'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

But doesn't work
i also tried to edit from virsh

```
virsh edit domain
```

and put

```
<qemu:commandline>
          <qemu:arg value='-L pc-bios'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

But give me this error

```
errore: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng
Element domain has extra content: qemu:commandline

Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]:
```

How to pass correctly qemu command line?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution using this workaround

[Converting QEMU arguments to domain XML](http://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sub-sect-Domain_Commands-Converting_QEMU_arguments_to_domain_XML.html)

After converting to xml import with

```
virsh create file.xml
```

Answer (score 24):

elbarna's own answer is the way to go for configuration options "natively" supported by libvirt (and thus its domain XML).
For qemu commandline arguments (and more) not supported by libvirt, you need to include qemu's XML namespace declaration in the 'domain' root element:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
```

Reference: https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#qemucommand

Comment: for servers who don't support kvm natively you can use `type='qemu'`

Comment: That schema is 404 now.

Comment: Seems they migrated to RelaxNG for the XML schemas. Though IDK if replacing above URL with `https://libvirt.org/schemas/domain.rng` works, if required at all.

Comment: @argonym No, does not seem to work out of the box.

Comment: I would add that in my case, parameters containing a space trigger an error, and must be given with multiple `<qemu:arg value=` lines

Comment: This still works, even if the schema is a 404.

Comment: This doesn't append the args, so you cannot reference any `id` or pci bus created by the domain XML.

Answer (score 7):

If you have `virt-xml` 1.4.1 (released in 2017, so should be widespread by now) or later in your path (provided by `community/virt-install` in Arch), you can use:

```
virt-xml $DOMAIN --edit --confirm --qemu-commandline '-my-args 1234'
virt-xml $DOMAIN --edit --confirm --qemu-commandline 'env=MY-ENV=1234'
```

to automatically add the XML corresponding to env vars and/or args, including the namespace. `--confirm` allows you to preview the changes before committing.

This is much more convenient than trying to manually paste in the XML namespace, and worked for me even though `virsh edit` was no longer accepting identical manual changes.

Ref: https://blog.wikichoon.com/2017/03/easy-qemu-commandline-passthrough-with.html